# Binding a Dropdown inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm binding a `DropDownList` inside a repeater and below is my mark up

```xml
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound">
      <HeaderTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Left</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Right</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>SubString</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

   </HeaderTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate>
  <br />
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

```cs
protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {

      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
      {

          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          dt = Common.LoadExample();

          DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList2");
          ddl.DataSource = dt;
          ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
          ddl.DataValueField = "Name";

      }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      throw;

  }
}
```

but I'm unable to fill the dropdown list as the breakpoint is skipping `e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header` here. How can I solve this?

Comment: I am placing the controls in Header template as they are being repeated if i place in ItemTemplate.

Comment: The controls are getting repeated 5 times

Comment: Look here for some ideas http://forums.asp.net/t/1193229.aspx/1

Comment: But i have problem with this e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType at first time it equals header and from the second time it is showing false.

Comment: There are some more ideas in this page

Answer (score 0):

For header row binding, move your code from `ItemDataBound` to `ItemCreated`

-- updated answer --

This will ONLY work once you add `ItemTemplate` without item template, setting blank datasource will not bind the grid in expected way.

Please add item template and bind some dummy data

Comment: It is not working I think the problem is with e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header  line

Comment: What i have to keep in ItemTemplate??Why to add some dummy data?Bbut i have the data in repeater i am having problem with this e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header

Comment: Since you are using repeater, you will have some data to bind, so bind it in item template

Comment: But i am having problem with filling the dropdown

Comment: You can still try it, may be you can get your solution!